# DB2: How to print few columns with conversion along with all other columns without having to write all the names of the columns?

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a table having 10 columns, with id, f_name, l_name ..... low_range, high_range, ...

I want to write a query which will print all my table, but just this low_range and high_range to be converted in hex.

I know two things:

```
 1. We can write all the column names and replacing the 
    low_range with hex(low_range) and high_range with high_range.
```

but this asks me two to write all the column names, which seems a bit unfair.

```
2. We can write a query like:
 select t.*, hex(low_range), hex(high_range) from table t
```

But it will give all the column names first and then the required fields in hex also after them, which I don't want to as there is a repetition of information.

Is there any other clean way to achieve this thing.

*PS: I am new to databases.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. The two ways you list are the only two ways to specify column output order, so you can either:

1. `select t.*` and then append your custom fields to the end (or the beginning) OR
2. List each field individually eg `select t.field1, t.field2, hex(t.field3), t.field4...`

The two methods you describe are the only ways to do this.

Comment: Dont you think that there should be a way to do this?

Comment: I'd love to be able to write something like `select t.* except t.field1, t.field2 from table t` where I was selecting everything EXCEPT a few fields that I could insert later - but you can't. This is why wide table SQL often ends up so verbose. There are reasons for this (as to why this isn't a feasible addition) related to indexing.